# Renaming multiple files asyncroniosly causing error in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I am trying to rename a bunch of pre-generated testing files (1000+) asynchronously in Node.js.

The code looks like the following:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { each } = require('async')

each(files, file => {
  let newfile = 'new' + file
  fs.rename(file, newfile, err => {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log('renamed')
  }
})
```

This leads to following error:

> Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '8d3320e35d22772f'
>   at fs.lstatSync (fs.js:902:18)
>   at Object.fs.lstatSync

It's not `async` module issue, since replacing `each` with native `forEach` leads to the same error. Also, there are no issues when using synchronous version of rename `fs.renameSync`.

I think it's trying to move some file twice or so but can't figure where exactly mistake is. Made this assumption, because all files have been already renamed successfully and very likely error generated afterward. Can someone advice what causing such behavior?

Comment: Can you show what the `files` array looks like? How does an example file path in this array look like?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. files array is fine. The synchronous version of rename `fs.renameSync` have no issues. Updated the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `fs.rename()` doesn't use `fs.lstatSync()`. Is that really the only code that's running?

Comment: my bad. the error came from underneath function `fs.lstatSync` took place in

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Just in case someone curious, this error came from following underlying function:

```
function rmDir(dir) {

    var list = fs.readdirSync(dir);

    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var dirOrFile = path.join(dir, list[i]);
        var stat = fs.lstatSync(dirOrFile);

        if(dirOrFile == "." || dirOrFile == "..") {
            // pass these files
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            // rmdir recursively
            rmDir(dirOrFile);
        }
//        else { fs.unlinkSync(dirOrFile) }                   // rm fiilename
    }
    fs.rmdirSync(dir);
}
```